# How to get a DOM elements click handler using capybara-webkit or native QtWebKit?

Tags: qt, capybara, qtwebkit, capybara-webkit

I'm using capybara-webkit and would like to get the event handler(s) bound to the click event of an element in the DOM. An answer even using native QtWebKit calls would probably be enough for me to figure out how to do it using the webkit driver in Ruby. The challenge I am having is that the event handlers are being bound programmatically in JavaScript, not in HTML, and my searches so far on how to do this all seem to end with how to click or otherwise trigger events in a QWebView. I need to inspect the event handler (i.e. the actual function definition), in particular anonymous functions bound to the event, without generating the event itself. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Good question, and I'm not sure of how you'd do that without doing something dirty like firing off some generic js when the user clicks an element and then picking that up... Not sure if it will help you but check out [`QWebElement`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwebelement.html). You can get a `QWebElement` for the root of the document with `QWebView->page()->currentFrame()->documentElement()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute arbitrary Javascript and return the result using `page.execute_script`. If the event handlers in question are bound using jQuery, this will list them:

```
page.execute_script(<<-JAVASCRIPT)
  var handlers = $('.some-selector').data("events").click;
  jQuery.each(handlers, function(key, handler) {
    console.log(handler);
  });
JAVASCRIPT
```

There's a complete answer on introspecting on event handlers here: [How to find event listeners on a DOM node when debugging or from the JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node/447106#447106)